# Should users lose points for unhelpful flags?

Tags: discussion, helpful-flags

I've meant to ask this. We can raise flags at any moment, but it is up to the admins of Stack Exchange to decide whether or not a flag is appropriate for a specific post. The question is, should users lose points after a certain number of unhelpful flags like 5 or 10?

Comment: FWIW, if a user is persistently flagging in bad faith in spite of flag bans, we will suspend them, which will temporarily put their reputation at 1.

Comment: This would only make sense if users *gained points* for helpful flags, which is obviously a ridiculous suggestion.

Comment: Declined flags are intended to be educational, not punitive. If we deducted reputation for declined flags, people would either stop flagging immediately or flag decline reasons on Meta would get way more contentious than they are. The relatively new flag warning system has been great at getting people to pay attention to reasons we're declining flags, and has led to good discussions here. I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not necessary.

There are already limitations on how often you can flag: you start with 10 flags per day, and this is increased with reputation and good flagging history.

[On the recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890)

Also, if too many of your flags are declined, you can get a flag ban. You will get a warning if you are in danger of a flag ban, too.

There is no need to further punish bad flaggers with reputation penalties. A ban serves that purpose more effectively and privately.